# Using updatepanel with gridview templatefield (ImageButton), Firing event but no changes in forntend

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

i am using updatepanel with templatefield whose itemTemplate is an imagebutton control. When the imagebutton is pressed the event behind the button is fired which is mend to populate the textfields which it does not do.

.aspx code:

```
                                          <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                                                        <Triggers>
                                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="_btnUserEdit" EventName="Click" />
                                                        </Triggers>
                                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="_btnUserEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" CommandName="" Height="30px" Width="30px" OnClick="_btnUserEdit_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
                                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>                                                    
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <ItemStyle Width="35px" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

C# code:

```
protected void _btnUserEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (EstablishmentDataContext db = new EstablishmentDataContext())
        {
            ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;

            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

            id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);

            var Edit = (from a in db.Users where a.UserID == Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text) select a).FirstOrDefault();

            _txtName.Text = Edit.Name;
            _Email.Text = Edit.UserEmail;
            _Password.Text = _txtConfPassword.Text = Edit.strPassword;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For using `AsyncPostBackTrigger` inside a `GridView` you need to add trigger in the `RowDataBound` event like this.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var editButton = e.Row.FindControl("_btnUserEdit") as ImageButton;
        UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(new  AsyncPostBackTrigger{  
            ControlID=editButton.UniqueID, 
            EventName="click"});
    }
}
```